# How do you execute a remote script on a remote host in R

Tags: r, cmd.exe, script

I am trying to figure out how to execute a remote .bat file on a remote host on that host, not on the localhost from R.  This syntax:

```
bcpImport <- shell("//remotehost/S$/SnowflakeCSV/BCP_Load_Script.bat")
```

runs on the local host and can't make the connection to SQL server. It needs to run on the //remotehost.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to define the remote server that BCP should run on with an `-S remotehostname\instance name` of the SQL Server instance that I was trying to load.